# How can I publish a snapshot artifact using sbt-release?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, sbt-release

I managed to set up sbt-release in my CI pipeline to publish a release artifact (e.g. v0.0.1). From that point in time, I can add local changes and the build versions change to snapshot along with my commits (v0.0.1-1-SHA1-SNAPSHOT). At this stage, how can I publish a snapshot artifact without releasing? I mean, I may not want to release v.0.0.2 at this stage, I only want to publish a snapshot. Also, I want to do that in such a way the version format is preserved and I do not need to manually input the version.

Comment: My basic setup follows http://blog.byjean.eu/2015/07/10/painless-release-with-sbt.html

Answer (score 6):

Eventually I responded to my requirements by using separate "sbt release" command for publishing a release artifact and "sbt publish" to publish a snapshot artifact. I also needed to set the publish location in the build.sbt file as follows.

```
publishTo <<= version { v: String =>
 val nexus: String = "https://xxxxxxxx/repository/"
 if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
   Some("Snapshots" at nexus + "snapshots")
 else
   Some("Releases" at nexus + "releases")
}
```

From the "sbt-release" section of the linked posted in my comment

*Below is a sample release process for an application, to switch it to a library you would uncomment the publishArtifacts and comment the next line which is used to publish the package from the Universal namespace.*

`releaseProcess := Seq(
  checkSnapshotDependencies,
  inquireVersions,
  setReleaseVersion,
  runTest,
  tagRelease,
 // publishArtifacts,
  ReleaseStep(releaseStepTask(publish in Universal)),
  pushChanges
)`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you added added 'sbt publish' task?

Comment: @TusharSudake as described in the "sbt-release" section from the link I posted, I added the publish step to the release process. Please see my updated answer above.